# Inverses and adjoints

Tags: category-theory, soft-question

If a functor has a two-sided inverse (i.e., is an equivalence), then its inverse is both left and right adjoint to it.

But suppose that a functor has a left inverse. Does it follows that it is left adjoint? (The converse can't be true, as a not every left adjoint is fully faithful.)

In general, is there *any* connection between (left or right) *inverses* and (left or right) *adjoints*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider posets as categories in the usual way. Consider $f : \{0\} \to \mathbb{N}$, $f(0)=1$ and the unique map $g : \mathbb{N} \to \{0\}$. Both are monotonic, hence functors with the usual ordering on $\mathbb{N}$, and satisfy $g \circ f = \mathrm{id}$. But $f$ does not preserve the largest element (in fact, $\mathbb{N}$ has none), so $f$ is not continuous, so $f$ is not a right adjoint. You also see that $f$ is not a left adjoint since $f$ does not preserve the smallest element.

Alternatively, consider the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{Ab} \to \mathbf{Grp}$ and the abelianization $F : \mathbf{Grp} \to \mathbf{Ab}$. We have $F \circ U \cong \mathrm{id}$, but $U$ does not preserve coproducts and hence is no left adjoint.